Gradle causes org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file when running with Intellij
When loading a Gradle project in Intellij, I sometimes get an exception that:
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\...jackson-core-2.15.2.jar

Most answers to this question point to a bug in Gradle versions prior to 7.6.2
In my case a gradle --version told me that I had version 8.10.1

I solved this by changing Intelij Settings.
File-> Settings-> Build, Execution, deployment-> Build Tools-> Gradle.
Right near the bottom of the settings there is a Use Gradle From dropdown.
The problem was resolved by choosing Specified location and browsing to my gradle installation (C:/Gradle/gradle-8.10.1)
